# Хранение контента страниц в БД

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Насколько я знаю, CMS хранят контент страниц в базе данных. Этот способ имеет кучу преимуществ.

Но вот такой вопрос. Есть страница, на которой сначала идет "статичная" информация (например, адрес, телефон компании и т.д.), потом должен быть список сотрудников, в конце еще какая-то информация. Список сотрудников лежит еще в одной таблице.

Как хранить страницу в одной таблице БД так, чтобы список сотрудников подгружался из другой таблицы?

Прощу прощения, если написал не очень понятно.

Comment: Используйте шаблонизатор и храните не страницы, а материалы (статьи). Тогда вы сможете выводить сначала 1й материал, затем инфу по сотрудникам, а потом 2й материал.

Comment: Спасибо, я и подумывал сделать нечто такое.

Comment: а просто SELECT JOIN не?) или в 2 запроса и статике кэширование поставить на месяц.

Comment: А что за SELECT JOIN? Я такого еще не знаю)

Comment: Погуглите на тему запросов с JOIN'ами(перекрестные, между несколькими таблицами), всяко полезно. Пример (стараюсь интуитивно понятный сделать) "SELECT * FROM table1 AS T1 JOIN table2 AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.parent_id WHERE T1.id = 15 LIMIT 1;"

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разделил контент на две категории - статьи(статичные) и компоненты(динамичные). Соответственно первые вывожу xxthtp echo? вторые через include.

Answer (score 0):

>>Этот способ имеет кучу преимуществ.

Например ?

Как выше сказали - используйте шаблонизатор.

Comment: Преимущество я знаю только одно - легко поменять содержимое из браузера, как при использовании CMS.

Answer (score 0):

join'ом тут не прокатит... пару запросов, один на контент, другой на мемберы, а после шаблонизатор